# Why is `None` returned instead of tkinter.Entry object?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.2

I'm new to python, poking around and I noticed this:

```
from tkinter import *
def test1():
    root = Tk()
    txtTest1 = Entry(root).place(x=10, y=10)
    print(locals())
def test2():
    root = Tk()
    txtTest2 = Entry(root)
    txtTest2.place(x=10, y=10)#difference is this line
    print(locals())
test1()
test2()
```

outputs contain:

`'txtTest1': None`

`'txtTest2': <tkinter.Entry object at 0x00EADD70>`

Why does test1 have a `None` instead of `<tkinter.Entry object at ...`?

I'm using python 3.2 and PyScripter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `place` method of `Entry` doesn't return a value. It acts in-place on an existing Entry variable.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it would return the Entry with that location, but your answer makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

because Entry.place() returns None

in a more C-like language you could do:

```
(txtTest1 = Entry(root)).place(x=10, y=10)
```

and txtText1 would be the Entry object, but that syntax is illegal in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I have done some c++/c# in the past so that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an object (`txtTest1`) and then calling a method on that object (`place`). Because you code that as one expression, the result of the final method is what gets returned. `place` returns `None`, so `txtTest1` gets set to `None`

If you want to save a reference to a widget you need to separate the creation from the layout (which is a Good Thing To Do anyway...)

```
txtTest1 = Entry(root)
txtTest1.place(x=10, y=10)
```