# Can you update the text and value of a radio button in tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, radio-button

I am using Python 2.7.6

I just started working with Tkinter recently and I am in the process of turning a command prompt quiz into a GUI quiz. So far I have been successful except when it comes to the radio buttons I am using. I can create a group of radio buttons and pull their values when need be, but I am uncertain how, if possible, to update the text and values of the radio buttons after I click the "Next" button.

This isn't my whole code since it is over 800 lines, but here is where I create the radio buttons and the watered down version of the function `def Guide():`  where I want to update the radio buttons.

Assume `Guide_list[Current].R1` and `Guide_list[Current].V1` retrieve the proper string and integer respectively.

"Current" is my counter.

```
from Tkinter import *
app=Tk()

Current=0
R=IntVar()
R.set(None)
Resp1=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R1, value=Guide_list[Current].V1,variable=R).pack(anchor=W)
Resp2=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R2, value=Guide_list[Current].V2,variable=R).pack(anchor=W)
Resp3=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R3, value=Guide_list[Current].V3,variable=R).pack(anchor=W)
Resp4=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R4, value=Guide_list[Current].V4,variable=R).pack(anchor=W)
Resp5=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R5, value=Guide_list[Current].V5,variable=R).pack(anchor=W)
Resp6=Radiobutton(app, text="N/A", value="N/A",variable=R).pack(anchor=W)
def Guide():
    global Current
    Current=Current+1
    ### Insert code to update the radio buttons ###

button2=Button(app,text="Next", width=15,command=Guide)
button2.pack(side='bottom')

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, can I ask if you are using any tutorials to learn Tkinter? I see a lot of people using the same "assignment+pack antipattern", and I'm trying to track down where they're all getting it from.

Comment: I was using various tutorials I found on Youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the attributes of a widget using the `config` method.

```
    def Guide():
        global Current
        Current=Current+1
        Resp1.config(text="Hello")
```

However, you can only do this if you still have an existing reference to the widget you're trying to config. As your code is now, you don't have this; Resp1 through Resp6 are all None, because you pointed them to the return value of `.pack` instead of the actual Radiobuttons. See also [Why is None returned instead of tkinter.Entry object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933572/why-is-none-returned-instead-of-tkinter-entry-object). You need to pack on a separate line.

```
Resp1=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R1, value=Guide_list[Current].V1,variable=R)
Resp2=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R2, value=Guide_list[Current].V2,variable=R)
Resp3=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R3, value=Guide_list[Current].V3,variable=R)
Resp4=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R4, value=Guide_list[Current].V4,variable=R)
Resp5=Radiobutton(app, text=Guide_list[Current].R5, value=Guide_list[Current].V5,variable=R)
Resp6=Radiobutton(app, text="N/A", value="N/A",variable=R)

Resp1.pack(anchor=W)
Resp2.pack(anchor=W)
Resp3.pack(anchor=W)
Resp4.pack(anchor=W)
Resp5.pack(anchor=W)
Resp6.pack(anchor=W)
```